# Allow me to set an edit reason when editing the help center

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

It would be nice if I could set an edit summary on this page:

[image: edit interface]

As it stands, the edit reason is automatically set to "Moderator edits article"

[image: result of edit]

I'd like to be able to give something more descriptive.